# Error:Apex trigger caused an unexpected exception: OpportunityUpdateClosePlanContactRole: System.LimitException: Too many DML rows: 10001

Tags: apex, trigger, dmlexception

Does anyone understand why this trigger keeps throwing an error in production? This code works perfectly in my sandbox and developer accounts, but in production I'm dealing with thousands of records. Can this code be modified to handle thousands or records?

```
trigger OpportunityUpdateClosePlanContactRole on Opportunity (after update) {

    List<close_plan_contact_role__c> cpcrList  = new List<close_plan_contact_role__c>( [SELECT Id FROM close_plan_contact_role__c] ); system.debug('Query CPCRList: ' + CPCRList);
    delete cpcrList;

    List<OpportunityContactRole> ocrList       = new List<OpportunityContactRole>([SELECT OpportunityId, ContactId, contact.name FROM OpportunityContactRole WHERE ContactId NOT IN ( SELECT Contact__c FROM close_plan_contact_role__c ) ] ); 
    List<close_plan_contact_role__c> cpcrList2 = new List<close_plan_contact_role__c>(); system.debug('Create empty CPCRList2');

    for(OpportunityContactRole ocr : ocrList){
        close_plan_contact_role__c cpcr = new close_plan_contact_role__c();
        cpcr.contact__c                 = ocr.contactId;
        cpcr.opportunity__c             = ocr.opportunityId;        
        cpcrList2.add(cpcr);
    }
    insert cpcrList2;
}
```

Comment: Yes, you just need to filter each query to use only the opportunity records inside Trigger.new. for example, the opportunitycontactrole query should add "AND OpportunityId = :Trigger.new" as a condition.

Comment: Side note: the result of a query is already a list. It is inefficient to create a new list from the query results.

Comment: Should my query look like this -- List<OpportunityContactRole> ocrList       = new List<OpportunityContactRole>([SELECT OpportunityId, ContactId, contact.name FROM OpportunityContactRole WHERE ContactId NOT IN ( SELECT Contact__c FROM close_plan_contact_role__c ) AND OpportunityId = :Trigger.new ] );

Comment: Secondly, should I take that query and, instead, put it in the for loop? Meaning, for(OpportunityContactRole ocr : [ query ])

Comment: I added an answer that demonstrates the query. Both cpcrList and ocrList are actually optional, if you wanted to inline the queries.

Comment: @sfdcfox -- Dude, plainly and simply...YOU. ROCK. Just had to add/create CPCRList2 after delete statement. I am humbled. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to filter for the opportunities that are in the current context, instead of the entire database:

```
trigger OpportunityUpdateClosePlanContactRole on Opportunity (after update) {

    delete [SELECT Id FROM close_plan_contact_role__c where Opportunity__c = :Trigger.new];

    close_plan_contact_role__c[] cpcrList2 = new close_plan_contact_role__c[0];

    for(OpportunityContactRole ocr : 
            [SELECT OpportunityId, ContactId, contact.name 
             FROM OpportunityContactRole 
             WHERE ContactId NOT IN ( SELECT Contact__c 
                                      FROM close_plan_contact_role__c 
                                      where opportunity__c = :Trigger.new) AND 
                   OpportunityId = :Trigger.new ]){
        close_plan_contact_role__c cpcr = new close_plan_contact_role__c();
        cpcr.contact__c                 = ocr.contactId;
        cpcr.opportunity__c             = ocr.opportunityId;        
        cpcrList2.add(cpcr);
    }
    insert cpcrList2;
}
```

Comment: Ok. Let me give this a shot in production. I'll report back in like 20 minutes to update you.

Comment: @IsBoyd Sure thing. I just added a few more optimizations if you want to use those, too.

Comment: Dude, plainly and simply...YOU. ROCK. Just had to add/create CPCRList2 after delete statement. I am humbled. Thank you. – IsBoyd 20 secs ago

Comment: @IsBoyd You're welcome. Always glad to help!